# How to get string from input in C language

Tags: c, input

This is what i have try:

```
printf("Please venter first string\n");
char str[127];
scanf_s("%s", &str);
```

And got this exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x0FD2C700 (ucrtbased.dll) in strcmp.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00500000.

I also try this:

```
printf("Please venter first string\n");
char str[127];
scanf_s("%d", &str);
```

In this case no exception but i got long and strange string.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", &str)` --> `scanf_s("%s", str, sizeof(str))`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY the `s` of `scanf_s`  means "safe"... well, you still have to check the warnings...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what warning?

Comment: not enough parameters, something like that. One can always hope.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry, thought you were comenting on BLUEPIXY.

Comment: I was commenting on how inefficient `scanf_s` safety is. had OP used scanf, it would have worked.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I quite agree, it is even more difficult to get right than `scanf` - which already has a length restriction feature.

Comment: yeah. Except that you have to go to some extents to avoid hardcoding the restriction, using stringing & macros. But `scanf` remains the standard

Comment: "How to get string from input in C language"? --> `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);` for happy programming life. `scanf_s` and `scanf` leads down the [road to perdition](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/perdition).

Comment: `scanf` is a [pernicious](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pernicious) function for new C programmers to use for user input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's start by considering the use of the standard `scanf`. If you write

```
scanf("%s", &str);
```

that will be incorrect (although it might work). When passing an array to a function it decays to a pointer to the first element, which is what `scanf` requires, so the line should be

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

If you want to restrict the input length to prevent buffer overflow it can be like this (one less than the array length to allow for the `nul` terminator)

```
scanf("%126s", str);
```

The allegedly safer function `scanf_s` requires an additional size argument to be passed for each format type `%c` and `%s` and `%[]` so the next line (after correcting the `&`)

```
scanf_s("%s", str);
```

lacks that argument, and the compiler should issue a warning about it. The code should be

```
scanf_s("%s", str, sizeof str);
```

but even that is inadequate. The `Xscanf` family of functions returns the number of values successfully entered. Since users (even myself) are notoriously bad at entering correct input (which may even be malicious) you must always check if the data was correctly entered. Such as

```
if(scanf_s("%s", str, sizeof str) != 1) {
    // inform user and retry etc. etc.
}
```

As mentioned by @chux it is better to obtain input by using `fgets`, and then process it by various means, such as `sscanf` or `strtok` or `strsep` or by more direct analysis of the string. In that case, and with `sscanf`, you can make multiple attempts to process the input, but with `scanf` you only get one chance. Note that `strtok` and `strsep` modify the string, so you would need to work with a copy if you need to make more than one attempt to decode it.

---

In your second example

```
scanf_s("%d", &str);
```

you got "no exception but a long and strange string", but you should have got a compiler warning:

> warning C4477: 'scanf_s' : format string '%d' requires an argument of
>   type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'char (*)[127]'

Note that you did not initialise `str` to the "empty string" and if you go on to process what you imagine to be a good string after a faulty input, bad stuff can happen.

Comment: `&str` is the address of the object, `str` decays to the address of the first element, which are not necessarily the same thing.